# Why if I instead consider a non-stationary process I get an autocorrelation that decays faster?

Tags: r, regression, time-series, simulation

I have a question concerning the autocorrelation of an AR (1) process generated with R through the following code

`set.seed(1)
x <- w <- rnorm(1000)
for (t in 2:1000) x[t] <- 0.9* x[t - 1] + w[t]
acf(x)`

It is a stationary process because 0.9 < 1

[image]

Why if I instead consider a non-stationary process I get an autocorrelation that decays faster? Should not it be the other way around?

`set.seed(1)
x <- w <- rnorm(1000)
for (t in 2:1000) x[t] <- 1.2* x[t - 1] + w[t]
acf(x)`

[image]

Comment: When the first order autocorrelation is close to 1 the the autocorrelation function decays slowly like a first difference model.  By taking the first difference you can get a process that looks stationary and could have faster decay than the AR(1) process. Consider the fact that .0.9 is an estimate of the first order autoregressive parameter and the "true" value could be 1 or higher. It is hard to distinguish between a stationary AR(1) process with the correlation parameter close to one and a random walk (first difference model).

Comment: But anyway the autocorrelation of the process with parameter 0.9 should expire faster than the autocorrelation of a process with parameter 1.2, or am I wrong?

Comment: That is not so. The first difference takes care of the high coefficient. A first difference is like making the parameter equal 1.

Comment: Instead of autocorrelation with coefficient 1.2 can it be deduced that the process is not stationary?

Comment: Of course 1.2 is not a correlation. It is the autoregressive parameter estimate in this case. The fact that the estimate is close to 1 could mean that the process is non-stationary, a random walk.